# Javascript error: Unexpected string in Parse cloud code

Tags: javascript, json, parse-platform

I'm trying to get info from an httpresponse, parse de JSON and create a new dictionary with an array of dictionaries like :

```
"data" :   {"infracciones": [
             {
            "folio": "03041487403",
            "fecha": "2014-03-16",
            "situacion": "Pagada",
            "motivo": "POR NO RESPETAR LOS LIMITES DE VELOCIDAD",

        }, 
        {
            "folio": "0334357403",
            "fecha": "2015-04-11",
            "situacion": "Pagada",
            "motivo": "POR NO RESPETAR LOS LIMITES DE VELOCIDAD",

        }],
        "tenencia":[ ...]
 }
```

but I'm getting en error : "Unexpected string in main.js:35" but I don't have a clue of what's happening, thanks for your help, here's the code:

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: url1 ,
    headers: {
 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    }
    }).then(function(httpResponse) {

        var json = JSON.parse(httpResponse.data);
        var datos = json.infracciones;
        var infracciones = [];
        var data = {};
        var i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < datos.length ; i++){


            infracciones[i].["folio"] = datos.folio ;  // THIS IS LINE 35
            infracciones[i].["fecha"] = datos.fecha ;
            infracciones[i].["situacion"] = datos.situacion ;
            infracciones[i].["motivo"] = datos.motivo ;

        }

        data.push({
            key : "infracciones",
            value : infracciones

        });


        response.success(data);
        console.log(httpResponse.text);
    }, function(httpResponse) {
      console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
});
```

Comment: Add this before that line `infracciones[i] = {};` and change `infracciones[i].["folio"]` **=>** `infracciones[i]["folio"]` **Removed dot operator**

Comment: Remove the . Or the [" and "] in that line and the next 3 as well

Comment: @Tushar thanks, but now I get this error = "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in \u003cunknown file\u003e:1", Do you know what could it be?

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks, now I get this error = "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in \u003cunknown file\u003e:1", Do you know what could it be?

Comment: You messed up the editing probably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
var infracciones = [];
var data = [];
var i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < datos.length ; i++){
    infracciones[i] = {};
    infracciones[i].folio = datos.folio ;
    infracciones[i].fecha = datos.fecha ;
    infracciones[i].situacion = datos.situacion ;
    infracciones[i].motivo = datos.motivo ;
}

data.push({
    key : "infracciones",
    value : infracciones
});
```